# Using my own cms on localhost and the fronted site on the server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I just wonder , for more security , can i put my own cms at localhost server that connected to DB , and the fronted site at live server , so the CMS will be more secure when its not live and its on localhost?

Comment: Frontend and CMS are the same things by term. You might have Backoffice and Frontend on seperate servers but that doesn't make it more secure by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could if you’re the only person using it and your MySQL database accepts connections from external machines.

Alternatively, you can protect your CMS from external access by using a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but is called "security by obscurity" and not a very good idea to do. Just make sure you program your CMS and your website on a safe way.

Comment: u all wrong , google and so on using there backoffice on localhost servers , and the fronted sites on live server , the localhost since he have local ip 127.0.0.1 and not have public ip , its more safest way..